# NSPredicate syntax for PHFetchOption keys

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm developing an app in Swift using PhotoKit.

I have close to no knowledge of Objective-C and am having a hard time wrapping my head around the syntax for NSPredicate expressions which are used to filter fetch results throughout the library.

The [documentation for PHFetchOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions) contains a table of **keys** that can be used in an NSPredicate via the PHFetchOptions.predicate. The [documentation for PHFetchOptions.predicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions/1624709-predicate) gives an example of how to use this but I can't make sense of the syntax:

```
fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaSubtypes & %d) != 0 || (mediaSubtypes & %d) != 0", PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama, PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
```

> mediaSubtypes & %d

What does the "&" do in this context?

> PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama

What's going on here? I get that this refers to *PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoPanorama* but how come this is all camelCased?

In my particular example I would like to fetch PHAssetCollections that are not empty by doing something like this:

```
    let smartAlbumsOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    smartAlbumsOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "estimatedAssetCount > 0", argumentArray: nil)
    smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: smartAlbumsOptions)
```

I am assuming that PHFetchOptions can somehow insert the value for all supported keys (i.e. estimatedAssetCount) into the expression string but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't make sense of the syntax ... What does the "&" do in this context?

Take a look at the docs:

> Because an asset may have more than one subtype, you use these values as bit masks to identify an asset

You picked a tough one, for sure, if you're not used to binary arithmetic.

`%d` is an integer (the raw value of `PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoPanorama` or `PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate`) that is going to be matched against a media subtype's raw value, which is also an integer — but it's a bitmask. That's so it can represent multiple values, which makes sense, because a piece of media can have more than one subtype simultaneously.

For example, a value of 6 (`110`) represents both 4 (`100`) and 2 (`10`). So we cannot use simple equality to express this. If we want `100`, we want any value *where that bit is set*, but we don't care about any of the other bits: `100` is a match, but `110` is also a match, and `111` is also a match, and `101` is also a match.

In Swift, we can break this down into an OptionSet and do setwise `contains` on it. But you can't do that in Objective-C, which is the language of predicates.

So we *bitwise-AND* the bits against `100`, thus changing everything except that one bit to `0`. For example, `110 & 100` is `100`, and `111` & `100` is `100`, and so on. But `010 & 100` is `0`. Okay, so if the result is *not* `0`, our bit was not `0`. Hence it was `1` and we have a match.

> how come this is all camelCased?

That’s how it looks in Objective C. See
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetmediasubtype/phassetmediasubtypephotopanorama?language=objc

> ```
> smartAlbumsOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "estimatedAssetCount > 0", argumentArray: nil)
> ```

Actually just leave off the second parameter:

```
smartAlbumsOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "estimatedAssetCount > 0")
```

> but I don't understand how.

That’s just how NSPredicate works. Objective C is highly dynamic and introspective so strings can represent the names of properties. Read the docs. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate

Comment: I see! Thanks for the great answer. So in the case of `(mediaSubtypes & %d)` _%d_ is replaced with the raw Int value of PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoPanorama and then compared to whatever goes into _mediaSubtypes_ ? By that logic this should work: `"estimatedAssetCount > 0"` It just looks like it always comes out as 0 regardless of what the real count of assets in the PHAssetCollection is. But I suppose the syntax is not the issue here.

Comment: Sorry but you are asking too many questions at once. I stopped after the first question.

Comment: Might want to learn about NSPredicate? https://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. And thanks for the link!